# Stuck trying to get the liquid gem to work in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, liquid

I'm building an app to learn rails better and I'm trying to implement the liquid gem

Just trying to keep it simple so I can get it working and understand it by just having @guide.name passed through the liquid template but when i put `{{ @guide.name }}` in the template it doesn't render at all.

category_item Controller

```
def show
     @guide = Guide.friendly.find(params[:guide_id])
     @category = Category.friendly.find(params[:category_id])
     @category_item = Category.friendly.find(params[:category_id]).category_items.friendly.find params[:id]
end
```

show.html.erb

```
<% template = Liquid::Template.parse(@category.template) %>

<%= template.render %>
```

and in @category.template is

```
the guide is {{ @guide.name  }}
```

If I just put `hello` in the @category.template it renders fine

I think I'm supposed add something in the category_item helper but i'm not sure what to put in there. Or maybe there are other places I'm supposed to add information as well.

Comment: Don't mean to sound hard but if you're just learning Rails why do you use such a non-standard tempting engine? It looks like someone tried to reimplement PHP Smarty in Ruby, which makes completely no sense to me...

Comment: It is the main solution for the app I'm trying to build. So users can edit page templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<% template = Liquid::Template.parse('the guide is {{ guide_name  }}') %>
<%= template.render('guide_name' => @guide.name) %>
```

basically passing a hash of your variables as a mapping to the ones that you are using in your template.

hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

Follow liquid gem documentation to better understand basics. In your case `Liquid::Template.parse()` should be like this:

```
 <% template = Liquid::Template.parse('the guide is {{ @guide.name  }}') %>
 <%= template.render('@guide' => @guide) %>
```

rule: `'string {{variable name only}} string '`

According to liquid gem documentation example:

```
 @template = Liquid::Template.parse("hi {{name}}") # Parses and compiles the template
 @template.render('name' => 'tobi')                # => "hi tobi"
```

Comment: Still just outputs 'the guide is' then nothing. The 'hi toby' implantation from their example works but i cant get variables like @guide to work

Comment: are u sure `@guide` is initialized? can u show me output of `@guide.inspect`